# CM13 x86 not rooted?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

I had Cyanogenmod 13 x86 installed on a USB Drive. I looked through the settings and could not find anything related to root, and I even searched for 'root', with no results. I am a little confused because I recently rooted my friends phone with CM13, and it has root.

So, **why does Cyanogenmod 13 x86 not have root?**

(PS) Notice the past tense, I no longer have it now, I will try to provide any more *details from memory* when asked.

Comment: It does. Enable Developer options first, then look inside.

Answer (score -3):

in developper mode you go to root access then you choose appliccations... and you have already root access